# minify sencha js is not working in webkit browser in tablet

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, android, mobile-webkit

i am new in sencha development and facing a problem in js.

minify sencha 2 js is not working in webkit browser  in tablet and mobile can anyone help me on it.

is there any way to debugging sencha js in webkit browser  in tablet.

Thanks

Comment: This question is somehow vague.  And actually, there are two questions! Could you elaborate on "js is not working" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information would be incredibly helpful. :)

The first step would be check the Web Inspector in Safari or Chrome. Check the console for any errors. If there are none, switch the User Agent in the browser to iOS to check if it is device specific there.

More information about debugging Sencha Touch with Web Inspector available here: http://robertdougan.com/posts/how-to-debug-sencha-touch-2-applications-part-1

If that still doesn't show the problem; you'll need to switch to remote debugging. The first step on iOS would be to enable the Safari Debug Console. Settings > Safari > Advanced > Debug Console. Check if the error then shows in the browser.

If you are on Android, there is a similar setting.

If you need to use remote debugger functionality (just like Web Inspector in Safari/Chrome) you could use Weinre. More information here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre